# NDSolve and Plot report Replace Issue!

Tags: mathematical-modeling, mathematica

[NDSolve and Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMAbr.png)

Thanks Anyone know what's the issue?
NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 9*x[t]*y[t]/(10*x[t] + 1), 
  y'[t] == 0.3*y[t]*(1 - 10*y[t]/(10*x[t] + 1)), x[0] == 0.15, 
  y[0] == 0.25}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 150}]
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. %%], {t, 0, 150}]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please edit your question in order to make it clear what you have and what you have attempted to do in order to solve it. And while you're at it, please use [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: You should ask this on [Mathematica Stack Exhange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) instead of here.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very long time I did not use Mathematica. Looking at the documentation, writing

```
 s=NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t]*(1 - x[t]) - 9*x[t]*y[t]/(10*x[t] + 1),
            y'[t] == 0.3*y[t]*(1 - 10*y[t]/(10*x[t] + 1)), x[0] == 0.15, y[0] == 0.25},
            {x, y}, {t, 0, 150}] 

 Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. s], {t, 0, 150}, PlotRange -> All]
 Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. s], {t, 0, 150}, PlotRange -> All]
```

would (in principle !) not make problems.

Thanks for letting me know.